# iPhone: Free developer certificate just for learning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i was wondering if i can get a iphone developer certificate for free?
I just want to learn objective-c and iphone development.

// No, the xCode iPhone Simulator don't have an accelerometer etc.

g.

Comment: Wondering does the current version of the iPhone SDK allow you to deploy without a certificate if you set the build SDK version to 2.0?  This might allow you to deploy 2.0 apps on 2.0+ devices...?  (Does the current SDK even have a 2.0 deploy option...  it's been a while.  I think this might of worked with older SDKs set to output for OS 2.0 but I can't quite remember)

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, no. It's not possible to get into the dev program without coughing up the dough :)

The dev kit (with the simulator) is good enough for most uses though, and you can certainly learn to develop on the iphone though that. As you mentioned, you don't get access to certain features, but such is life.

Comment: Agreed about the simulator. If your goal is to learn iPhone development, you can go a long way down that road using just the simulator.

Answer (score 6):

As everyone has already said you can't get a free certificate. If however your at university it might be worth asking around the various departments to see if they have signed up for a university licence, this is how I've got my development certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The free developers kit that provides the simulator will let you learn how to do 90% of iPhone coding without having to use an iPhone. If you're new to iPhone development and don't know for certain you will be releasing apps for it, I think the getting an actual developer's license is a waste of money.

Instead, get the free stuff and use it to learn the ropes and then only get the license if and when you decide you what to learn the last 10% and/or release an app.

Answer (score 0):

By jailbreaking your phone, you will not be able to always update your phone to the latest version, and therefore as a developer will face the problem when you sync your phone to your computer to test your code, that you will not be doing it with the latest version and Apple do not look kindly to people who release software that is older than the latest version available

Comment: The jailbreak scene seems to keep pretty well up to date with new releases.

Comment: Yes mate but you are still one step behind until it is done, and with the risk that it may not always get the latest version

Answer (score -1):

You should check out [Apple's developer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/) website. They have objective-c and iPhone development tutorials there.

Comment: He asked not on tutorials, but on if it is possible to get a developer certificate for free. This answer is irrelevant.